# Detect if "Share" dialog is opened

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

How can I detect if the "Share" dialog was opened?

There are a lot of options for opening the "Share" dialog, once it's opened I want to do a manipulation in the dialog.

I didn't find a way to catch the dialog once it's opened. I don't want to use focusing on the people picker input.

Answer (score 0):

The share dialog contains a div with id `sharingDialogmainContentRegion`. You can check for presence of this div element to know if share dialog has been opened.

To do this, you can call this function somewhere on page load, but you need to ensure that this is called on every page.

```
var timeOutHandle = null;
function checkDOMChange()
{
    var ShareDialog = document.getElementById("sharingDialogMainContentRegion");
    if(ShareDialog != null) {
        //Do your manipulations

        //----------
        //stop calling the function after timeout
        if(timeOutHandle != null) {
            clearTimeout(timeOutHandle);
        }
    }
    else {
        // call the function again after 100 milliseconds
        timeOutHandle = setTimeout( checkDOMChange, 100 );
    }
}
```

The futuristic way to do this would be using [Mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/MutationObserver) when all browsers start supporting it but for the time being this would work across all browsers.

Comment: thanks. but it will work for whole pages all the time....Im getting a loop. im working with IE 11 and chrome

Comment: did you use the edited code? one else condition was missing in first version.

Comment: yes but its loopppping

Comment: the function will loop until it finds that the dialog has been opened. It will stop executing once it finds the dialog opened.

Comment: I found this option $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {}); its seems that its working fine....